# .Bat Duplicate file X times?

Tags: file, batch-file, duplicates

I need a batch process to duplicate a file specified number of times. 
Currently I repeatedly copy paste in order to multiply a file .

I've scoured the internet for `.bat` codes which does this. 
With no luck ; I'm not a programmer.

Hoping for something simple as drag drop . Setting  number of duplicates needed within the .BAT itself without heavy use of CMD .

If possible I need something as simple to duplicate a file specified number of times.

Comment: We expect a single specific issue per question, and that issue requires fully explaining and a [mcve] of the code which exhibits that issue. Please provide the code you're using to duplicate a file a specified number of times, and sufficient supporting information for us to replicate that issue and help you.

Comment: Without code your question is off topic on StackOverflow, as we cannot fix something which doesn't exist. I would therefore suggest you delete this question and post it instead on a more suitable site, perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you better explained your requirement in a comment, this would seem to be what you need.

```
@echo off
set /p num=Enter number of times you want to copy file:
for %%a in (*) do if not "%%~fa"=="%~0" (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "ext=%%~xa"
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do copy "%fname%" "%name%%%i%ext%"
pause
```

The `if not "%%~fa"=="%~0"` is simply to ensure we do not do the same duplication for the batch file itself.

to add 1 less file than entered:

```
@echo off
set /p num=Enter number of times you want to copy file:
set /a num+=1
for %%a in (*) do if not "%%~fa"=="%~0" (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "ext=%%~xa"
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do copy "%fname%" "%name%%%i%ext%"
pause
```

or to delete the original file:

```
@echo off
set /p num=Enter number of times you want to copy file:
for %%a in (*) do if not "%%~fa"=="%~0" (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "ext=%%~xa"
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do copy "%fname%" "%name%%%i%ext%"
del "%fname%" /Q
pause
```